# Where are opesource requirements analysis and design documentation

Tags: open-source, analysis

It's very easy to get the code of an opensource project, but it's different for the higher level artifacts.

Is it because it's called open **source**, is it because I can't find it, or what? Is there a place where I can get some good projects to study?

Comment: I don't think this is related to project management. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [ReadySET](http://readyset.tigris.org/), which is a Tigris project. They provide a number of templates for standard documentation - project proposals, planning, QA, design, test, releases.

Comment: I don't think that is what @ecoologic is asking for. He is not asking for open source tools to develop software; I understand he is asking how to obtain models and other documentation of existing open source products. Is that right, @ecoologic?

Comment: Maybe. I read it a few times, it looked like he was looking for documentation that is "open source" (released under an open license). But you might be right. I'm not entirely sure now that I reread it again.

Comment: I actually read it as he's looking for some sort of solution for providing documentation for a project. (ie: phpDoc, etc)

Comment: I'd like to learn how to write good analysis, and being a software developer, that is the kind of docs I'm interested in. I've got the feeling I misunderstood the meaning of the site, better to know it at the beginning, I'm read the faq and it doesn't seem to be wrong, I go back to area51 and have a better look there